# Add class to parent div by child element id

Tags: jquery

I have following html:

```
<div class="ugc-input-wrapper">
<label for="attachment_caption">Caption</label>
<textarea name="post_content" id="attachment_caption"></textarea>
</div>
```

Want to add class to div by using inner content here for example textarea id i.e,

```
    <div class="ugc-input-wrapper classname"><div>
```

How to do this by jquery.

Comment: You wanted to use the content of the `text area` as `class name ` in the `div`?

Comment: no I just wanted to give any class to div.

Comment: OK, then what triggers it? How do you want to add the class? On load, by click or what?

Comment: Just on load....

Comment: If you want to add a class on load, why don't you render it server-side to avoid JS hazzle?

Comment: You means by manually adding class to div?

Comment: The question title is misleading, you want to add class name by its content? what do you mean by that? While in your comment, you just want to add a class to div.

Comment: question title has changed

Answer (score 0):

Its Simply: (want to do this)

```
$('#attachment_caption').parent().addClass('caption');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var id= jQuery('#attachment_caption').attr(id);
jQuery('.ugc-input-wrapper').addClass(id);
```

You can do this to get the id of textarea and adding it as a class to the div.

Comment: OK..will try and tell you..